# is Last 4-digits of credit card and Expiry Date storage allowed in PCI-DSS?

Tags: pci-compliance, pci-dss

We need to store last 4 digits of credit card, (in order to let customers know which card they have used?) and expiry date (to notify customers that their card is about to expire) for our subscription/recurring payment based SaaS application.

are those two data storage allowed in PCI DSS? Please answer with reference/link to official website or document.

Please note: We are not storing **Name On Card** and **CVV numbers**

Comment: @JohnConde I researched enough. I read multiple answers in SO itself. I went through multiple PDF docs from www.pcisecuritystandards.org. There is no clear answer, that is why I asked question to get the advice from expert.

Answer (score 4):

You should be ok w regard to PCI regulations.

This table lays out what data can be stored:
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf

"If required for business purposes, the cardholder’s name, PAN, expiration date, and service code may be stored as long as they are protected in accordance with PCI DSS requirements."

-edit-
According to the bottom table in that doc, it says you should be able to store those elements.  Since you are not storing full PAN, Regulation 3.4 shouldn't apply to the other elements.

If it helps, we got Level 1 certified and we store last 4 and expiration date in clear text.  You don't need audited unless you are Level 1 (assuming Merchant here, not Service Provider).

Comment: Thanks. But the key sentence here is "they are protected in accordance with PCI DSS requirements.". This means we need to have the storage and data center must be audited as per PCI and DSS guideline. According to these docs, it mentions that if you are storing PAN, your storage must be PCI DSS compliance. But I am not able to find anywhere that says Last 4-digits+expiry date combination will require the same.

Comment: Name, last 4, and exp date are not SAD (sensitive auth data).

Answer (score 4):

From what I am reading within the PCI Data Storage Do's and Don'ts PDF (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf)

You are able to store the expiration date, service code, and cardholder name so long as you do **NOT** store the PAN.

Direct quote from the PDF:

> These data elements must be protected if stored in conjunction with the PAN. This protection should be per PCI DSS requirements for general protection of the cardholder data environment. Additionally, other legislation (e.g., related to consumer personal data protection, privacy, identity theft, or data security) may require speci c protection of this data, or proper disclosure of a company’s practices if consumer- related personal data is being collected during the course of business. PCI DSS, however, does not apply if PANs are not stored, processed, or transmitted.